# Changing widget background at runtime

Tags: android, background, widget

I am developing a simple widget and I would like to change the background at runtime from a png file (or similar). Is this possible to do and if so, how? Can someone provide some simple example?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like:

```
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widgetBackground, ((BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.YOUR_BACKGROUND)).getBitmap());
```

File `YOUR_BACKGROUND` is a png.

The `views` Object is an instance of `RemoteViews`.
You can get the instance by using:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
```

And don't forget to update the Widget after these changes.

```
AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
ComponentName me = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
mgr.updateAppWidget(me, views);
```

Comment: What sort of view are you using this on?  I tried it on a LinearLayout and had Android blow up on me:

Comment: Problem loading widhet if widget layout is a ListView

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background image or any other value using the setInt or other methods in RemoteViews.

remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_layout,
      "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.myshape_red);

The above sample is what I used to change the widget to another drawable shape.  You need to pass in an "id" rather than just the layout reference though.

Please note that this does not work with 2.1.

Comment: This doesn't work, throws the following warning:
W/AppWidgetHostView(152): android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: android.widget.ImageView can't use method with RemoteViews: setBackgroundResource(int)

Comment: Seems to work when I did it here.  https://github.com/trajano/GasPrices/blob/master/src/main/java/net/trajano/gasprices/GasPricesWidgetProvider.java  (see line 27 to 46)

Comment: Now I've tried it on Android 2.1 and it worked. Before that I've tried it on Android 1.6 and it did not work. It's weird as the documentation says this method is available since API Level 3..

Comment: Actually it does not work for me, but it won't get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [View.setBackgroundResource(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)?

Comment: How wouldyou get the "view" from RemoteViews?